# check to see if a sub array exists in JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Here is the json Sample:

```
    {
   "kind": "shopping#product",
   "id": "tag:google.com,2010:shopping/products/6582229/17914968800165668776",
   "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products/6582229/gid/17914968800165668776?alt\u003djson",
   "product": {
    "googleId": "17914968800165668776",
    "author": {
     "name": "Red Tag Market",
     "accountId": "6582229"
    },
    "creationTime": "2010-11-30T10:00:00.000Z",
    "modificationTime": "2011-05-01T09:20:00.000Z",
    "country": "US",
    "language": "en",
    "title": "The Fantastic Mr. Fox - BLU-RAY/DVD",
    "description": "Wit.",
    "link": "ht361",
    "condition": "new",
    "gtin": "00024543657552",
    "inventories": [
     {
      "channel": "online",
      "price": 22.51,
      "currency": "USD"
     }
    ],
    "images": [
     {
      "link": "http://208.131.143.232/i/6/3/0/7/6/1/8.jpg",
      "thumbnails": [
       {
        "width": 60,
        "height": 60,
        "link": "hBEevU46OsArJElwIeErF_3E7Zzu12M2eLSvQBdYiMLaRWrI60aF8lHxRqOz-wkx2YJUIVdCrzrEQDWxgcc"
       }
      ]
     }
    ]
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "shopping#product",
   "id": "tag:google.com,2010:shopping/products/6296724/17894083551590155418",
   "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products/6296724/gid/17894083551590155418?alt\u003djson",
   "product": {
    "googleId": "17894083551590155418",
    "author": {
     "name": "eBay",
     "accountId": "6296724"
    },
    "creationTime": "2011-04-04T00:43:02.000Z",
    "modificationTime": "2011-04-04T00:43:02.000Z",
    "country": "US",
    "language": "en",
    "title": "Fy.",
    "link": "htt530831212&itemid\u003d140530831212&icep_meta_categ_id\u003d11232",
    "condition": "used",
    "gtin": "00024543657552",
    "inventories": [
     {
      "channel": "online",
      "price": 14.99,
      "currency": "USD"
     }
    ],
    "images": [
     {
      "link": "http://i.ebayimg.com/00/%24%28KGrHqYOKkQE1r4Vh1gFBNl4n0t17g%7E%7E_1.JPG?set_id\u003d8800005007",
      "thumbnails": [
       {
        "width": 60,
        "height": 60,
        "link": "http://lh
       }
      ]
     }
    ]
   }
  }
```

What I want to do is see if `data.items[i].product.images[]`  exists or not.  as you can see the Images array does not present in the second response thus killing my javascript at the point I try to use `data.items[i].product.images[]` for any purpose.  I have been looking and have yet to find a solution.

Edit:
I just tried this and still no dice:

```
if(data.items[i].product.images !== undefined){
    var image = 'images/inverticon.png';
}else{
    var image = data.items[i].product.images[0].thumbnails[0].link;
}
```

I do not get any errors, the script just stops running. If I omit the image code everything works fine and as long as the returned JSON has the image[] it works fine.

Edit:
 here is the solution:

```
if(data.items[i].product.images !== undefined){
    var image = data.items[i].product.images[0].thumbnails[0].link;
}else{
    var image = 'images/inverticon.png';
}
```

Comment: It's not clear whether you're checking this in JavaScript or PHP.

Comment: Have you had a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+check+nested+property

Comment: @ross it is in javasscript. I removed the php tag my apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (data.items[i].product.images !== undefined) {
  //do what you will
}
```

trying to access a property of an object that does not exist will return undefined. That's most likely the error you were getting?

Do you know about the web inspector tool in web browsers? They all have a console that any errors get outputted to. If you check that, then you'll see what's wrong.

You're still trying to access the images array in the else of that condition statement, that will cause an error.

It should be like this,

```
if(data.items[i].product.images !== undefined){
  var image = data.items[i].product.images[0].thumbnails[0].link;

} else {
  var image = 'images/inverticon.png';
}
```

'not equal to undefined' is equivalent to saying 'is defined'

Comment: I have tried this and still the code just breaks and stops when ever i try to access "data.items[0].product.images" if it does not exist then it does not even say undefined.  heres is the current block 'if(data.items[i].product.images == undefined){
 var image = 'images/inverticon.png';
}else{
 var image = data.items[i].product.images[0].thumbnails[0].link;
}'

Comment: Update your answer with the exact details of what's happening, errors for example. Also, clarify that the problem is with JS and not PHP for the other people watching.

Comment: your last recommendation is what I needed. I guess that I just never did it that way.  I think its time for a break. Thanks a bunch. :)

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you don't parse it into a PHP array then check? You tagged your post PHP so I assume that's what you're using.

```
$myarray = json_decode($json);
if (isset($myarray->items[0]->product->images)) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I apologize for that I used php to return my info to javascript and then its all js from there. 'parent.Wants('<?php echo json_encode($return); ?>','<?php echo $lkeID; ?>');'